# Rabbitmq vs Apache QPID

Tags: c++, apache, rabbitmq, amqp

Im trying to figure out which of these two messages queues to go with. I was initial interested in RabbitMQ but have been a bit discouraged by the fact that it (rabbitmq) do not provide a stable C/C++ client and seems to have no persistent storage (?)

Answer (score 4):

RabbitMQ does indeed have persistent storage. It is provided out-of-the-box through the Erlang database technology [Mnesia](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/mnesia.html).

You should be able to use the [C++ Qpid client with a RabbitMQ broker](http://www.rabbitmq.com/interoperability.html). Wire-level interoperability is one of the benefits of using products compliant to the [AMQP standard](http://www.amqp.org/) (which both [Qpid](http://qpid.apache.org/amqp.html) and [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/amqp-concepts.html) implement).

Comment: As it turns out, Apache QPID and RabbitMQ is on different versions of the AMPQ spec and therefor its not possible to use the Apache QPID C++ client with RabbitMQ

Comment: Certain versions of Qpid and RabbitMQ will interoperate just fine. Have you tried it?

Comment: Its only older, non-maintained (as I understand it), versions of QPID client that might work against some Rabbit broker.

Comment: Old post, but now there is something about QPID persistence [here](http://qpid.apache.org/releases/qpid-cpp-1.39.0/cpp-broker/book/chapter-ha.html#ha-store) and [here](http://qpid.2158936.n2.nabble.com/How-do-I-create-a-queue-larger-than-available-RAM-td7643861.html)

Answer (score 2):

Are you migrating away from JMS? I believe the biggest benefit to Qpid is its analogs to JMS - it tries as much as possible to provide the same interface that the ActiveMQ client libraries might have but using AMQP as a wire-level protocol.

If you are starting from scratch, best to go with RabbitMQ. The client libraries will allow you to best leverage header exchanges and the like, and the server instances are generally more mature.

Comment: JMS abstraction is also an issue. If you follow AMQP terminology, Its more difficult to understand how to have binding key etc...JMS does not have notion of exchange....Also, documentation and user group is also an issue. Not many are there to provide you help...